# How to mock SQL Server database connection using jest

Tags: sql-server, typescript, testing, jestjs, mocking

I want to mock a SQL Server connection.

Here is the code to be tested:

```
import sql from 'mssql';

export class DBConnection {

    public async query(input: any): Promise<any> {

        const config = {
            server: "server",
            port: 1234,
            database: "db",
            user: "user",
            password: "password",
            trustServerCertificate: true
        };

        try {
            const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

            await pool.connect();

            let request = pool.request();
            request.input('key', sql.VarChar, input.key);
            request.input('value', sql.VarChar, input.value);

            let insertQuery = "INSERT INTO SOMETABLE (key, value) OUTPUT INSERTED.key VALUES (@key, @value)"

            return await request.query(insertQuery);


        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

    }
}
```

My question is: how to create mock of `sql.ConnectionPool`? I tried using `jest.Mocked` to mock entire module, tried using `jest.spy` to mock the constructor or specific method, but seems none of them working

Here is the mock test, apparently not working

```
import { DBConnection } from './db';
import sql from 'mssql';

jest.mock('mssql');

const mockpool = sql as jest.Mocked<typeof sql>;
const pool = mockpool.ConnectionPool;

let db = new DBConnection();

describe('DB test', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {

        jest.spyOn(sql.ConnectionPool.prototype, 'connect').mockImplementation(() => pool);

    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it('should have success response', async () => {

        const input = { key: 'key1', value: 1234 }
        try {
            const response = await db.query(input);
            expect(response).toBe("key1");
        } catch (e) {
        }

    });
});
```